# Year 2023: gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node-gyp

I have Ubuntu on WSL and I keep getting this error while trying to run `npm i` :

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.4 and node@14.21.3 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1515:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
```

I have already tried the following without any luck to resolve this:

> npm set strict-ssl false
>
> npm config set ca=""
>
> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
>
> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
>
> npm config set enableStrictSsl false
>
> export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
>
> sudo update-ca-certificates
>
> git config --global http.sslverify "false"

etc
[image]